# How to add node require libraries to path?

Tags: node.js, macos, unix

After installing bitcoinjs and firing up node and running :

```
var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
```

I receive error :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'bitcoinjs-lib'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at repl:1:15
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:262:27)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:431:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
```

When I run these commands it appears to find the library :

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
$ ls
bitcoinjs-lib   browserify  npm     uglify-js
$ node
> var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
undefined
```

I think it works in this case because I'm running node from library `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

How can I add the modules library to node so can find a required library from any location instead of having to change directory into /usr/local/lib/node_modules?

I've tried modifying path in bash_profile to :

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

But this does not fix issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this working the quick way, you need to set `$NODE_PATH`:

```
NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

However, in general, Node modules shouldn't be installed globally (which means in a "system directory" like `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`).

Instead, you create a project directory, and install the module there:

```
$ mkdir my-project
$ cd my-project
$ npm install bitcoinjs-lib
```

If you run Node in that project directory, `require('bitcoinjs-lib')` will work.

Comment: thanks, I installed globally so can use library from repl

Answer (score 3):

A hacky way:

```js
module.paths.unshift(<path>);
```

```js
process.env.NODE_PATH = <path>
module.constructor._initPaths();
```

I figure out the above solution when I wrote a Cocos Creator(based on Electron) plugin which is loaded during the IDE opening. And I need to `require` a utils script from that plugin which is not located in any require paths. I tested the first code snippet in CC and Node.js v10.16.0 for Win10.