# Base path for `require()`

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, es6-modules

Note! I went through many answers before asking the question but did not find the answer I want. Please, do not mark it as a duplicate.

In es modules we can set `baseUrl` in `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "/base"
  }
}
or
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

Then we can import any files from that base directory throughout the project:

```
import Grand from 'base/child/grands'
```

I want to achieve the same thing in commonjs syntax (which uses `require()` ). I want to be able to import files(modules) like this:

```
const Grand = require('base/child/grands')
```

not this way:

```
const Grand = require('./base/child/grands')
```

How can I achieve this?

> P.S. I am working on a Next.js project which uses 'es modules' for frontend and 'commonjs' for backend.

Comment: Sad Node.js doesn't have the `-I` flag...

Comment: Also, try taking a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032289/how-to-add-node-require-libraries-to-path)

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV You could look into using [`module-alias`](https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias).